recaptcha working locally but not on heroku
I have an app running in heroku to which I am trying to add a recaptcha v2 checkbox. This is working fine locally but as soon as I deploy it to heroku I get the error 'ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type' . The heroku app is using the same site keys as I was using locally and I have added both the heroku dns and my own custom domain to the list of domains for the recpatcha key, so can't see any reason for this error. I am also using the same service account user and pem key as I am locally. Can someone please help me with this. thanks

Hi, as stated in this question it is advisable to generate a new key
